# Netbeans not picking up the latest Maven project archetype

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm having an issue with Netbeans when trying to create a Maven project from an archetype although a similar issue exists if trying to specify a dependency from a public repository.

But in the first instance, when I try to create a project from the apache-karaf-feature archetype (for example) although I know there is a later version, and I know it is available (see screenshot below) for some reason Netbeans does NOT pickup the latest version, as illustrated below.

[image: Trying to create karaf-feature project from the archetype]

I have tried the following to resolve the problem:

1. Refreshing/Updating the (Netbeans) repos in the 'Service' tab
2. Re-starting Netbeans
3. Re-indexing through the 'Options' dialogue.
4. Using system installed Maven instead of the Netbeans-bundled one.

No matter what I try Netbeans doesn't show me the latest although I can manually override the version number, but this should not be necessary.

No matter what I try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working for me. Ie it is showing version 4.01 when I search for karaf-feature.

Other things to try:

- Clear out the netbeans user config and cache directories ( see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)
- Click the show older checkbox in Project setup dialog. Maybe it sees 4.01 but has the versions in the wrong order.
- Check your maven settings.xml
- Try a manual generate from the command line to see if it works from maven.

Enter:

```
 mvn  -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchitypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes -DarchitypeArtifactId=karaf-feature-archetype -DarchitypeVersion=4.0.1 archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.foo -DartifactId=myArtifact -Dpackage=org.foo
```

Comment: Checking the 'show older' did it. Scrolling down the list I could see the 'later' version (4.0.1).